# Duda con animaciones en Android

Tags: java, android

La primera duda es como detener la *animación* una vez realizada, ahora mismo es un bucle y quiero que solo haga una vez la *animación* y stop:

```
    ImageView img_check_guia3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_guia_parte3);
        img_check_guia3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_check_guia3);

        AnimationDrawable animacion = (AnimationDrawable)img_check_guia3.getDrawable();
        animacion.start();

}
```

Y la otra duda es, ¿cómo puedo hacer para que no se ralentiza mi aplicación al abrir la clase con la animación?

`animacion`

```
<animation-list   android:id="@+id/handimation" android:oneshot="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_01" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_02" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_03" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_04" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_05" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_06" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_07" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_08" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_09" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_10" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_11" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_12" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_13" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_14" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_15" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_16" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_17" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_18" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_19" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_20" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_21" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_22" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_23" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_24" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_25" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_26" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_27" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_28" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_29" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_30" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_31" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_32" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_33" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_34" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_35" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_36" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_37" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_38" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_39" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_40" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_41" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_42" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_43" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_44" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_45" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_46" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_47" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

Obviamente si utilizo menos imágenes se va haciendo más fluida, pero necesito que sean 47 para tener una animación completa.

- Son 47 .png
- 700x700
- Cada png alrededor de 16kb
- En total todas las imágenes no llegan a 1mb

¿Qué podría hacer para que no se ralentice? No creo que con 3GB de RAM y 801 Snapdragon no pueda con esa animación.

Gracias

**EDITO3:** @MarcGV

`clase`

```
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import otrointento.dos.R;

public class GuiaParte3 extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView img_check_guia3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_guia_parte3);

        img_check_guia3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_check_guia3);

        AnimationDrawable animDrawable = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            animDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) getDrawable(R.drawable.movimiento_check_guia3);
        }

        img_check_guia3.setBackgroundDrawable(animDrawable);

        animDrawable.setOneShot(true);
        animDrawable.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: hola, para que necesitas correr tantas imagenes? quieres hacer como un gif? si es eso, deberias usar Glide https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 1):

Referente a como parar la animación:

> La primera duda es como detener la animación una vez realizada, ahora
>   mismo es un bucle y quiero que solo haga una vez la animación y stop:

```
animacion.setOneShot(true);
```

---

Referente a

> Y la otra duda es, ¿cómo puedo hacer para que no se ralentiza mi
>   aplicación al abrir la clase con la animación?

Para solucionar esto en un caso que me encontré, yo puse el primer frame de la animación en el imageview para mostrar el primer frame mientras cargas la animación, después se carga la animación en background `doInBackground()` con `AsynkTask` y una vez cargada se cambia el primer frame por la animación entera en el `onPostExecute()`

**Ejemplo:**

En el `ImageView` `src` pon el primer frame:

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/grid_alert"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/check_01"/>
```

Después creas un `AsynkTask` dónde cargas la animación y cuando esté cargada, pones la animación al `ImageView`

```
AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, AnimationDrawable>() {

    @Override
    protected AnimationDrawable doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return ContextCompat.getDrawable(R.drawable.animacion);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(AnimationDrawable animationDrawable) {

        img_check_guia3.setAnimation(animationDrawable);
        animationDrawable.setOneShot(true);
        animationDrawable.start();

        super.onPostExecute(animationDrawable);
     }
};
task.execute();
```

También puedes evitar el `AsynkTask` y poner la animación directamente. De esta manera verás el primer frame y una vez cargada verás la animación, aunque se hará todo el trabajo en el thread principal.

**EDIT**
Debes usar el método `getDrawable()` adecuado, el de ContextCompat es por si usar AppCompatActivity.
Para la animación cambia el método `setAnimation()` por `setBackgroundDrawable()`

```
//AnimationDrawable animDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(R.drawable.animacion);
AnimationDrawable animDrawable = getDrawable(R.drawable.animacion);

img_check_guia3.setBackgroundDrawable(animDrawable);
animationDrawable.setOneShot(true);
animationDrawable.start();
```

Comment: Vale, ahora si lo he conseguido hacer funcionar y aunque reduce el lag, sigue sin ser totalmente fluido.. @MarcGV he añadido mi ´clase´ tal cual la tengo por si ves que pueda haber hecho algo mal